# Multiplying multiple variables by a scalar

Tags: python

I have four variables: `x`, `y`, `height`, and `width` (all integers or doubles). I want to multiple all four by some number, `a` (also an integer or double). It's possible to write

```py
x *= a
y *= a
height *= a
width *= a
```

Is there a more concise, one-line version of this?

Comment: Not really, no.

Comment: If you're using numpy: `box = np.array([x, y, w, h])` then you can just scalar multiply-equals with `box *= a`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do with unpacking:

```
x, y, height, width = x*a, y*a, height*a, width*a
```

Comment: You don't need the parentheses, and spaces would be nice (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, no need to write `a` four times

```
>>> for i in [x, y, height, width]:
        print(a*i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke `__mul__` magic with `map` (this is an ugly, added it for sake of variation):

```
>>> x,y,height,width = map(a.__mul__,(x,y,height,width))
```